# Preventdefault until two successive clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I'm trying to prevent default link click action in a menu. I have it working with the below code, however, I noticed that when I click `Link 1` then `Link 5` and then go back to `Link 1` the default action occurs.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="page1.html">Link 1</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="page2.html">Link 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="page3.html">Link 3</a></li>
           <li><a href="page4.html">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page5.html">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(".menu a").one("touchstart, click", false);
```

What I'm trying to do is this:

1. Prevent default action on the first click of the element
2. If another menu item element is clicked, reset `.one()` for the first element, so when it's clicked again, the default action doesn't immediately occur until a second successive click is made.

Comment: If I understand you well, it means a click event will never successfully execute. Because you prevent the default action every time

Comment: No, clicking on the same element twice (in succession) allows the default behavior. Clicking on an element once, then another element, then going back to the first element would prevent default.

Answer (score 2):

Like this [Example](http://jsbin.com/cusizo/edit?html,js,output)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var lastClicked;

  $(".menu a").on("touchstart click", function(e){

    if(lastClicked!==$(this).attr('href')){
      e.preventDefault();
      lastClicked=$(this).attr('href');

     }


  });
});
```

Comment: Note that I set the real `hrefs` only on `link3` and `link4`

Comment: Your solution does indeed work, but I noticed some issues on mobile devices with getting the submenu to show on first click. Something a bit more JS and css classes can take care of. Alternatively, the data attribute solution works as well without the need for additional JS and css. Thanks for offering this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use data attributes, to set temporary value.

**Example ideology:**

```
<a href="page1.html" data-proceed="false">Link 1</a>
<a href="page2.html" data-proceed="false">Link 2</a>

$('a').click(function(e) {
    $('a').not(this).attr('data-proceed', 'false'); // reset to false for all other links. Use classes as per your requirement
    if($(this).attr('data-proceed')==='false')
    {
        e.preventDefault(); // if this is the first time
        $(this).attr('data-proceed', 'true'); // so that from the next click it will proceed
    }
});
```

Comment: but of course you know that it'll affect every 'a' tag on page?

Comment: @lupatus: OP needs to use selector classes as per his/her requirement, This is just a sample ideology for his/her understanding.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work well. And yes, I'm using more targeted selectors.